# UIButton not responding near the bottom of the screen on iPad

Tags: ipad, ios, uikit, uibutton

a UIButton isn't responding to any touches when it's positioned near the bottom of the screen on iPad (near the home button). It has touch enabled and it is taking in events, but no response is ever set to the target. I've checked the view hierarchy and it definitely is on top. It is not covered by the menu bar.

This happens only on iPad and only if it is on the bottom, I don't have a problem with iPhone, the code is the same for both devices?

Does anyone have a clue what might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I figured out what the problem was.

It was the dimensions of UIWindow. I mixed up width and height (I create the UIWindow programmatically, just to be clear) of it. Since I set the dimesions of the subviews correct, they were displayed correctly, but couldn'T get touch events where there wasn't a window underneath. Just to be safe, I'm using this from now on:

```
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem with an iPad app not responding except in the top left quarter of the screen, but with an universal app that loads the main window from MainWindow.xib.

As the app is universal, and does not have two variants for the .xibs, the size of the main window in the xib is iPhone. When run on the iPad, this is not visible, as by default UIWindow's clipsToBounds property ("Clip Subviews" in XCode inspector) is NO, which means that subviews can draw outside the window's bounds, and thus visually appear full screen (If you want to see it, just set clipsToBounds to YES in the UIWindow; helps to understand).

**To make sure the window gets full screen bounds when loaded from its .xib, there's an option called "Full Screen At Launch" in the XCode properties** for Windows. Note this does not correspond to a public API property of UIWindow, so that's something easily overlooked when just browsing UIWindows class documentation.

However, this IS highlighted in the "View Programming Guide for iOS", section "Windows", under "Creating Windows in Interface Builder" in a special box labelled "Important"...